# Microsoft Teams: Messaging Extension with Search-based commands

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm testing Teams Messaging Extension for Search-based commands. After creating solution with "YO TEAMS" and creating BOT in Azure with BotId / AppId and password / Secret. And put these as values in .env file in solution.

By running the command "gulp ngrok-serve" I get ngrok url generated and things look like it should be fine. But by uploading a .zip file from the package folder in Teams, I get the error message "Unable to reach app, Please try again".
[image]

Just to test, I have created another solution with only "Tab". And I get almost the same error message when I try to upload .zip,
"There was a problem reaching this app"
[image]

There are many frustrating tutorials some old and some new. By running the command "gulp ngrok-serve" you start ngrok for tunnel. And ngrok URL that is generated seems to work:
[image]

And the URL is stored as an endpoint for BOT in Azure:

[image]

So what have I missed here since it does not work?

Here is my manifest file:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.6/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.6",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "packageName": "{{PACKAGE_NAME}}",
  "developer": {
    "name": "gonadn consulting",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "TeamsMsgExtSearch",
    "full": "TeamsMsgExtSearch"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "{{MICROSOFT_APP_ID}}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "msgSearchCommandMessageExtension",
          "title": "MsgSearchCommand",
          "description": "Add a clever description here",
          "initialRun": true,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "parameter",
              "description": "Description of the parameter",
              "title": "Parameter"
            }
          ],
          "type": "query"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{HOSTNAME}}"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false
}
```

Link to [Git Repo](https://github.com/gonadn/teamsmsgextsearch)

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: By setting "showLoadingIndicator": false the test solution with only tab start working. I had same setting i manifest file for Messaging Extention with search command but i get the same error as explained above....! Tab start working...

Comment: i get same error with clean message extention Action based solution....!! Tab solution start working after changing showLoadingIndicator from true to false....

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added the same Botid as Bots for ComposeExtension in your manifest? Please share your manifest with us. Also, could you please try putting a debugger and see if it hits the code when you invoke message extension?

Comment: I have provided BotId as it is explained in .env file, and the BotId is the same as AppId. Iam sharing my manifest file. And i have done it in same way for solution with Tab.

Comment: Here is link to git repo for the teams app with search command: https://github.com/gonadn/teamsmsgextsearch

Comment: Could you please try out the sample here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

Comment: I have tried this sample, not working at all. Missing files ect in this solution you are ref to.

Comment: Does the solution hit your code when you invoke Compose Extension? Did you try putting a debugger and test? Can you please add some code on how you are sending back the response?